# Using Enum values in html attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net

can some one please tell me why this does not work, because im lost, kind of new to c# and coming from php environment

```
<asp:ListItem Value="<%:(int)Student.Classes.Enum.Enum.gender.male%>">Male</asp:ListItem>
```

but if i use this exact code outside it works perfect e.g

```
I am <%:(int)Student.Classes.Enum.Enum.gender.male%>
```

Comment: What do you expect to see and what _are_ you seeing?

Comment: i expect to see **1**, when i use it alone like the second line of code, i get **I am 1**, which is right, but in the first, that whole line is printed as is, like its text

Comment: That's what you did. You are giving the list item _value_ a 1, but the text is `Male`. Did you look at the HTML source to see what it looks like?

Comment: I see you are using classic ASP.NET Web Forms -- I wouldn't recommend this for new development. Use Razor engine "Web Pages" instead. It's a much simpler and more modern approach that works with HTML instead of against it. See http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: this is whats in the html **<option value="&lt;%:(int)Student.Classes.Enum.Enum.gender.male%>">Male</option>
**

Comment: i know about razor engines, but unfortunately i cant use that because of some school regulations :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was recommended, you should use .NET MVC instead of webforms, so instead of using `<asp:ListBox>`, you should use `@Html.DropDownList` 
Learn more about it here:
http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/how-to-simple-html-dropdownlistfor-mvc-net/

Your code for the dropdown/listbox would be:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StudentGender",
    new List<SelectListItem>() {  
        new SelectListItem(){ Text="Male",Value=Student.Classes.Enum.Enum.gender.male.ToString() },
        new SelectListItem(){ Text="Female",Value=Student.Classes.Enum.Enum.gender.female.ToString() }
    }, new { @class = "input-medium", size="6", multiple="multiple" } )
```

You can still use ASPX for the render engine in .NET MVC, which in that case you would use:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList(...) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty with this kind of thing, @chris is right, get into MVC if your starting on C#, etc. ASP.Net will be dead in 5-10 years.

anyway, I'm presuming you've got something like this:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" Id="listBox">
</asp:ListBox>
```

you prob want to set this in code:

```
public Page_Load()
{
    listBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Student.Classes.Enum.Enum.gender));
    listBox.DataBind();
}
```